# Magento2 review block overwrite

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-enterprise-2

Hi am try to review block function overwrite. but it's not working. I am trying both way preference and plugin not working please check and let me know what I am going wrong. 
*registration.php*

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Revoamerica_Categoryreview',
    __DIR__
);
```

*etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Revoamerica_Categoryreview" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Review" />
        </sequence>
</config>
```

*etc/di.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
         <type name="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View">
            <plugin name="Categoryreview-block-block-review" type="Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Plugin\ReviewPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
        </type>  
    </config>
```

*Plugin/ReviewPlugin.php*

```
<?php

namespace Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Plugin;

class ReviewPlugin
{    
    public function aftergetReviewsCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $name)
    {
        // logging to test override    
        die("testtt");
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to use method like aroundgetReviewsCollection, beforegetReviewsCollection etc.. while using plugin. 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change GetReviewsCollection by after plugun by below code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

class ReviewPlugin
{
    public function afterGetReviewsCollection(\Magento\Review\Block\Product\View $subject, $result)
    {
        // logging to test override
        die("testtt");exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this code but it;s not overwrite the getReviewsCollection review module function.

Comment: Delete var and generated folder and check again. I have checked and it's working.

Comment: How can i delete var and generated folder i will delete directly folder or i need run some command in terminal

Comment: Delete directly from

Comment: I have deleted folder and i have install new magento and tested its not working at my end